# joining two databases with two sets of criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I have 2 databases that I'm looking to pull into one query. 
Here's the structure

> Db1

```
tblA
patientID     UniqueID    
23            1787S
25            0989S

tblB
patientID     ApptType       ApptDate
23            1              1/1/2018
25            2              1/1/2017
```

> DB2

```
tblC
patientID     UniqueID
3             1787S


tblD
patientID    ApptType       AppDate
3            1              2/2/2016
```

This is much simpliefied data structures, but should be sufficient to get the query I need:
Basically many of the patients in Both Databases are the same, and this is what however, they have different patientID's which makes it difficult. They do have the same UniqueID's.

I want to look for clients in `DB1` that have `AppType = 1`. then hoping to join `DB2` and only select those clients that have `AppType = 1`,however, only show those clients that have a matching `UniqueID`

Result would look something like:

```
DB1_patientID         DB2_patientID         AppType        UniqueID
23                    3                     1              1787S
```

So I only see this client, because in both databases it matches the first criteria - `AppType = 1`, and in both databases that client has the same `UniqueID - 1787S`

Here's what I tried but I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
Select a.patientID, c.patientID
From ((tblA a inner join DB2.tblC c on (a.UniqueID = c.UniqueID)) inner join tblB b
a.patientID = b.patientID) inner join DB2.tblD d on c.patientID = d.patientId
group by a.patientId, c.patientID
Having (b.appType = 1 and d.appType=1)
```

This query gives me results, howver since I have like tens of thousands of records, it's hard to verify if everything is correct.

Comment: So run it on test data. Like you would have if you had prepared a [mcve] which is required to post a code question like this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like

```
select 
    DB1_patientID =   A.patientID,
    DB2_patientID =   C.patientID,
    AppType       =   D.ApptType
    UniqueID      =   C.uniqueid
from
tblA A
join tblB B
    on B.patientID=A.patientID
    and B.ApptType=1
join db2..tblC C
    on A.uniqueid=C.uniqueid
join db2..tblD D
    on C.patientID=D.patientID
    and D.ApptType=1
```